# josegonzalez plugin multiple imageupload not working in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

This code working in single image upload.

```
$this->addBehavior('Josegonzalez/Upload.Upload', [
 'photo'
]);
```

But below code not working in multiple image upload in cakePHP 3.

```
$this->addBehavior('Josegonzalez/Upload.Upload', [
  'photo',
  'video'
]);
```

how to upload multiple images in josegonzalez plugin??

Comment: what is missing in this code??

Comment: the code you've put in the question doesn't do anything. Ask yourself this question: "can readers know, understand and replicate the problem I am having from what I've put in the question?" - the answer is no.